# Dart Parse to/from json a library class using json_serializable

Tags: flutter, dart

- I'm working with [geocoder library](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder) in flutter.
- When I get an [Address](https://pub.dev/documentation/geocoder/latest/model/Address-class.html) I want to save it in [firebase

  firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) as an user (object) atribute but to do that I need to
  serialize the address (convert it to a map).
- Currently, I'm using [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) to parse from/to map my
  User class.
- Because Address is a class from geocoder library I'm having troubles to parse it to/from map because this is handled by json_serializable.

This is my User class:

```
    import 'package:geocoder/model.dart';
    import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

    import './resource.dart';

    part 'user.g.dart';

    @JsonSerializable()
    class User extends Resource {
       User(this.email, this.name);

       String email;
       String name;
       List<Address> addresses;

       factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);

       Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
    }
```

- I tried creating a new class called UserAddress whose parent would be Address like following but I'm getting an error

> The constructor returns type 'Address' that isn't of expected type 'UserAddress'.dart(invalid_cast_new_expr)

in the named constructor UserAddress.fromJson:

```
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user-address.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class UserAddress extends Address {
  UserAddress();

  factory UserAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      Address.fromMap(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => this.toMap();
}
```

Please give me some options to achieve parsing to/from map, please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to decorate library's class with your own. You can use `@JsonKey` annotation to set functions for (en)decoding library's `Address` object.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user_address.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class UserAddress {
  UserAddress(this.address, this.oneMoreField);

  @JsonKey(fromJson: _addressFromJson, toJson: _addressToJson)
  final Address address;
  final int oneMoreField;

  factory UserAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserAddressFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserAddressToJson(this);
}

String _addressToJson(Address address) => jsonEncode(address.toMap());
Address _addressFromJson(String json) => Address.fromMap(jsonDecode(json));
```

Example usage:

```dart
final testUserAddress = UserAddress(Address(
  addressLine: 'test',
  coordinates: Coordinates(10, 20)
), 1);

final json = testUserAddress.toJson();
print(json);

final decoded = UserAddress.fromJson(json);
```

prints:

```
{address: {"coordinates":{"latitude":10.0,"longitude":20.0},"addressLine":"test","countryName":null,"countryCode":null,"featureName":null,"postalCode":null,"locality":null,"subLocality":null,"adminArea":null,"subAdminArea":null,"thoroughfare":null,"subThoroughfare":null}, oneMoreField: 1}
```

As you can see, all nested objects are encoded fine.

**UPD**: When doing that via inheritence, you'll have to pass all base class' fields to super constructor and to override nested objects fields with `@JsonKey` annotation:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class UserAddress extends Address {
  UserAddress({String addressLine, String countryName, this.coordinates, this.oneMoreField}) 
    : super(addressLine: addressLine, countryName: countryName);

  @override
  @JsonKey(fromJson: _coordinatesFromJson, toJson: _coordinatesToJson)
  final Coordinates coordinates;

  final int oneMoreField;

  factory UserAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserAddressFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserAddressToJson(this);
}

String _coordinatesToJson(Coordinates coordinates) => jsonEncode(coordinates.toMap());
Coordinates _coordinatesFromJson(String json) => Coordinates.fromMap(jsonDecode(json));
```

result:

```
{addressLine: test, countryName: null, coordinates: {"latitude":10.0,"longitude":20.0}, oneMoreField: 1}
```

But I recommend using composition over inheritence in this case.

Comment: Can the answer be implemented removing the attribute Address in UserAddress because UserAddress extends Address in order to implement a solution to parsing UserAddress as Address directly?