# How can I map json data from API into my own dart model without declare any class property in my dart class

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

**Example:**

> **Dart class**

```
Class Product{
  String name;
  double price;
  Product(this.name,this.price);
}
```

> **Json data**
> final json = {
> "data": {
> "name": "Pen",
> "price": 2.2,
> }
> };

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate with `json['data']['name']` but it's better to go thought a model with a fromJson method
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59007000/14394936